# a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE=EXC_i386_GPFT) error in CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m in the evalJsHelper2 method

Tags: ios, cordova, exc-bad-access, file-transfer

I am getting a *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* (CODE=EXC_i386_GPFT) error in *CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m* in the *evalJsHelper2* in the following code line:

```
NSString* commandsJSON = [_viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

this error occurs when downloading multiple files at the same time. i tested the same app in iOS 7 it worked fine but not iOS 8. i am using phonegap 3.7 and the file-transfer-plugin

do you have any idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` handling has matured a great deal with `iOS8` and there are several changes to the API.

Check out http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/ for more info

Comment: thanks for the info, but this still dosen't solve the problem.